# Running EntityFrameworkCore on Xamarin iOS throws type initializer exception

Tags: c#, ios, entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project and a MVC Core project with a shared class library which contains an AppDbContext and my repositories. When running on MVC all my Get methods work fine but on Xamarin Forms iOS, I get the following error:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.      --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception.      --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: sni.dll assembly:
>   type: member:(null)

The line the code fails is the last line of the below (In my OnAppearing):

```
string connectionString = "user id=test; data source=test.internal.com,3002;initial catalog=testDB;password=test";
AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>().UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options);
PersonRepository repo = new PersonRepository(context);
var results = await repo.GetAll();
```

Previously I was using Dependency Injection but I'm using the above just to find the issue.
My PersonRepository GetAll method looks like the below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetAll()
{
    return await context.Person.ToListAsync<Person>();
}
```

And my AppDBContext looks like the below:

```
public class AppDbContext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (var foreignKey in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.NoAction;
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said this code works on MVC but not Xamrin iOS. I am using most up to date nugets:

- EFCore 3.1.2
- EFCore.SQLServer 3.1.2
- Shared Class Library .NetStandard 2.1
- Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.356

I've looked at other posts but couldn't find anything that relates to Xamarin or iOS. I've tried installing Microsoft.Data.SQLClient and Microsoft.Data.SQLClient.sni to the shared but this didn't resolve the issue.

Note:

- Xamarin iOS is set to No Linking
- Running on iOS simulator (Can't try physical device right now)

Comment: You cannot use sqlserver in xamarin, use service web if you want request db

Comment: @JeePakaJP thank you for your reply. I've tried it previously (EntityFrameWorkCore 2) and it worked fine. I thought EntityFrameworkCore was compatible with Xamarin iOS. Is this incorrect? How would I use service web instead? Why won't EF-Core work?

Comment: You can use EFcore but not SqlServer, if you want use get data online, create a REST service to consume data. If you want create local database on your phone use SQLite

Comment: Hi, @JeePakaJP. I'm just looking back at my old code and I definitely got SQLServer working with EFCore 2.2.6 on Xamrin iOS. Has support changed since then?